# char * SEGMENTATION FAULT

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to copy data from a buffer which i know its length to a char[] starting from a given index, the problem is that the data contains null, so the program crashes for a segmentation fault error.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
char *tmp = list->at(0); //list->at(0) return a pointer to the data
char *pEnd = tmp;
for (i = 0; i<size;i++)
{
     buffer[i] = *pEnd ; //<<<-----here I got the segmentation fault
     pEnd++;
}
```

Comment: If `list->at(0)` evaluates to null, then why would you expect this to do anything but seg fault.

Comment: list[0] is a buffer which hold a Cam data, this data could contains null.

Comment: When you fix the segfault, why bother with that for loop? Wouldn't memcpy make more sense?

Comment: what I am lookink for is a way to copy a bulk of data from the buffer without looping using pointers

Comment: I tried memcpy and the same seg fault !!

Comment: @us2012 this is not the real code,  it's a small one to make the question easier

Comment: of course it still seg-faults, you are still atempting to de-reference a NULL pointer?

Comment: sorry for that guys, just found the error, it was a missing & in the original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are saying that `list->at(0)` returns `NULL` Then the pointer `pEnd` will be `NULL`.

Therefore doing this `*pEnd` is de-referencing a NULL pointer which will obviously seg fault.

If you want to chek for this, you could check the pointer before de-referencing. for eg:

```
if(pEnd == NULL)
    //Do nothing or throw error or something
else
    //Go ahead and do your stuff
```

Comment: the problem is that it goes to the else section and then give me a seg fault !!